# How to access parent variable from child

Tags: javascript

I am trying to access a variable in A from B (in my example bellow).
I didn't extend B from A, because A is just a container.

```
function A() {
  var Parent = this;
  this.container = [];
}

A.prototype.add = function(Item) {
  Parent.container.push(Item);
}

function B() {

}
B.prototype.exec = function() {
  console.log(Parent.container[0]) //Uncaught ReferenceError: Parent is not defined
}

var Manager = new A();
var Item = new B();
Manager.add(B);
Item.exec();
```

How to access `Parent` from `Item` ?

Comment: You can't. In your examplpe, `Item` is just an item in the `Manager`'s `container` array. It has no idea where it is, or what it has access to in its parent "scope". Something you could do is put a new property in `B`, like `parent`. Then, in your `A`'s `add` method, you set `Item.parent = this;`. Then, from your `B` methods, you can access `this.parent`. Or do the opposite - have `B` accept a parent as an argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function A() {
  this.container = [];
}

A.prototype.add = function(Item) {
  //assigning parent property only if Item is added
  Item.Parent = this;
  this.container.push(Item);
}

function B() {
   this.Parent = null;
}
B.prototype.exec = function() {
  console.log(this.Parent.container[0])
}

var Manager = new A();
var Item = new B();
Manager.add(Item);
Item.exec();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function A() {
  this.container = [];
}

A.prototype.add = function(Item) {
  this.container.push(Item);
}

function B(Parent) {
   this.Parent = Parent;
}
B.prototype.exec = function() {
  console.log(this.Parent.container[0]) //Uncaught ReferenceError: Parent is not defined
}

var Manager = new A();
var Item = new B(Manager);
A.add(B);
B.exec();
```